# Camera capture task is not working after migrating to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 from 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I migrated my app from 8 to 8.1. The CameraCaptureTask which was working fine before is crashing the app with the exception shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Note: I am using Xamarin Shared project.